# Unable to run any apt-get command

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

This is a weird problem and I can't find a direct solution.

I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` (I haven't ever run it on this machine but it is Ubuntu server 12.04 like all the others).

It goes through the updates and get part way through upgrade then I get this error

```
(Reading database ... 80%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'mysql-common' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Now I am getting this same error when I try to run any apt-get command.

I have tried:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install -f mysql-common
apt-get install --reinstall mysql-common
```

And maybe some others that I can't think of now.

Most of the time, not always, and I can recollect exactly what commands it happens on (I have been hacking at this for a while now) it ends with that error. I am still unable to update.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Rehatcc's answer lead me to check out the mysql-common.files per the error `files list file for package 'mysql-common' is missing final newline`

The file is just garbage text.

Is this like a template file that is generic across all systems? Can I just paste in the text from another system?

Comment: tried to remove/purge mysql, and then update/upgrade and install it again? Just might work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to:

`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info`

Type

`ls -l mysql*`

If a file comes up such as "mysql-common.list" or "mysql-common.md5sums" or anything, do the following:

`sudo mv ./mysql-common.list ~/mysql-common.list`

and if this exist

`sudo mv ./mysql-common.md5sum ~/mysql-common.md5sum`

Reboot the system. Then let us know what is your status afterwards (not working... working... semi working...)

Note: If they are there in that directory, cat them open and see if there is a blank line at the end or hidden characters etc. (`cat ./mysql-common.md5sum`). If you are unable to tell if there are hidden characters in those files messing them up run do this (it removes all letters and numbers and slashes which would be in those files):

`cat ./mysql-common.list | egrep -v [[:alpha:]]`

Anything showing after that except /. or /.. is your problem line.

Comment: My dude. Maybe your way is better than mine but this is what I did. I copied and pasted the contents from another machines mysql-common.list file and it worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Anytime brother. Glad I could help (which isn't that often haha!)

Also don't forget if I were use, i would repair the mysql installation just to make sure there are no lingering bugs still lying around that might cause this again!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue with a different package (linux-libc-dev).

Here is the solution that worked for me (partly building on RedHatcc's answer):

*Note: the code samples refer to package `linux-libc-dev\:armhf.list` -- replace this with the name of your package.*

1. Verify the list file is invalid

   ```
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
   cat linux-libc-dev\:armhf.list
   ```

   An invalid file will appear empty or contain non-alphanumeric characters.

   A valid package list will include plain-text paths like this:

   ```
   /.
   /usr
   /usr/include
   /usr/include/sound
   /usr/include/sound/asequencer.h
   /usr/include/sound/asound.h
   /usr/include/sound/sfnt_info.h
   ```
2. Delete the invalid package list

   ```
   sudo rm linux-libc-dev\:armhf.list
   ```
3. Force APT to reinstall the package, recreating the deleted package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev --reinstall
   ```
4. Verify the list file is valid

   A valid package list will include plain-text paths like this:

   ```
   /.
   /usr
   /usr/include
   /usr/include/sound
   /usr/include/sound/asequencer.h
   /usr/include/sound/asound.h
   /usr/include/sound/sfnt_info.h
   ```

   An invalid file will appear empty or contain non-alphanumeric characters.